# Multivariate Rayleigh

Tags: st.statistics

What is the closed form formula (pdf) for a multivariate Rayleigh distribution. Is it -

$x^T \Sigma^{-1} x \times \exp(\frac{-x^T \Sigma^{-1} x}{2})$

How do you prove it is from the exponential family?

Answer (score 0):

See this [2003 paper by Ranjan Mallik.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbkcp2bjojj09pc/rayleigh.pdf?dl=0)